# Can I differentiate CSS on the different input types?

Tags: css

input type=text/radio/checkbox - can I treat them differently in my CSS?

Other than by adding `class=` I mean

Answer (score 14, accepted):

YES!

With an awesome thing called attribute selectors:

```
input[type="text"] { width: 200px; }
```

Just change that `text` there and you're good to go!

But note that these don't work on IE6, so you might want to take a look at the [dean.edwards.name IE7.js](http://dean.edwards.name/IE7/) :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the attribute selector, like this

```
input[type=text] { ... }
```

However, this is not supported in all browsers. Your safest bet is to use a class

Answer (score 4):

You can use `input[type=text]` to do this. Old browsers might not support it though.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes you can**

eg

```
input[type="text"]{
/*do something*/
}
```

**and more**

```
input[type="text"] {
font:bold 10px/12px verdana,arial,serif;
padding:3px;
}
input[type="button"],input[type="submit"] {
/* you know what to do */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do input[type="text"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
input[type="What ever the type you want to style specifically"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen this done (and I've personally tried). I believe you would have to have some JavaScript/jQuery run on the page post render to manipulate the classes of objects based on element attributes.